# swing KeyListener не отлавливает нажатие

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {


                JFrame frameMain = new JFrame();
                frameMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JPanel label = new JPanel();
                JButton button = new JButton("Button");
                label.add(button); // Вопрос 3

                frameMain.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                HelloComponent helloComponent = new HelloComponent();
                frameMain.add(helloComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frameMain.addKeyListener(helloComponent); // Вопрос 2

                frameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frameMain.setSize(400, 400);
                frameMain.setVisible(true);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HelloComponent extends JComponent implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener {

    String theMessage = "Hello";
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;


    public HelloComponent() {

        //addKeyListener(this); // Вопрос 1
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        g.drawString(theMessage, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {     }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {     }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            theMessage = "olleH";
            repaint();
        }
        else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            theMessage = "Hello";
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {    }
}
```

**Вопрос 1**

Если в конструкторе добавлять `addKeyListener(this)`, то он не работает и при этом `addMouseMotionListener(this)` работает нормально.

**Вопрос 2**

Если добавлять во `Farame frameMain.addKeyListener(helloComponent);` все работает, но перестает если добавлять кнопку.

**Вопрос 3**

Потом не удается установить фокус. При этом мышка перерисовывает как нужно.

Подскажите где и что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Компонент порождает `KeyEvent`ы, только когда находится в фокусе. Чтобы ваш компонент мог получить фокус автоматически, нужно вызвать для него `setFocusable( true )`, или сделать привязку клавиш через Input Map (да, `isFocusable()` возвращает `true`, но фокус не передается, [так задумано (JDK-6530201)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6530201)).
2. Поскольку окно не содержит компонентов, которым может отдать фокус, оно оставляет его себе, поэтому ваш компонент получает события, порождаемые окном. Кнопка может получить фокус и получает, а ваш компонент снова не видит нажатия.

Небольшие доработки для иллюстрации:

```
public HelloComponent() {
    setFocusable( true );

    addKeyListener(this); // Вопрос 1
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
        // перерисовка при получении и потере фокуса
        @Override public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) { 
            repaint();
        }
        @Override public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });

    addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
        // запрос фокуса при нажатии мыши
        @Override public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
            requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    g.setColor( isFocusOwner() ? Color.RED : Color.ORANGE );
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
    g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
    g.drawString(theMessage, x, y);
}
```

- [Java Turtorials: How to use focus subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: Спасибо, то что доктор прописал ))